# Show unit tests for xamarin android in test runner

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.android

I would like to write unit tests for xamarin.android who are executed directly on the device. But I would like the tests to show up in the test runner and can be started from there. Does exists anything like this?

What I saw is what xamarin and xunit offers. But both of them needs to manually deploy an app and start it manually on the device.

Comment: You are looking for `Xamarin.UITest` (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/) These tests automate the application on a local device (or emulator or Xam's Test Cloud) and are executed from the Dev UI or cli via unit-console

Comment: Is mit UI test not meant testing the UI of the app? ^^